# Inquiry Regarding URL Redirection Issue on PHP-Based Website

Tags: php, url

My dear friends, I have a question regarding my website, which was designed using PHP. I'm currently trying to change the URL of a specific page from:

[www.example.com/index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=70&act=70&](http://www.example.com/index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=70&act=70&)

to:

[www.example.com/company-exhibition](http://www.example.com/company-exhibition) or [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog)

I've attempted to modify the .htaccess file and used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=70&act=70&$ https://example.com/blog [L,R=301]
```

However, no changes have occurred, and the target page hasn't changed as required. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions for this issue?

change the URL of a specific page from:

[www.example.com/index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=70&act=70&](http://www.example.com/index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=70&act=70&)

to:

[www.example.com/company-exhibition](http://www.example.com/company-exhibition) or [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog)

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only; if you want to match on query string contents, you need to do that with a RewriteCond.

Comment: Your PHP script will likely _need_ those query string parameters to display the desired content though, I suppose? What you actually need to implement then, is the "other direction" of this - when the client requests `/company-exhibition`, you need to internally rewrite that to `/index.php?page=show&ex=...`, so that your PHP script knows what you actually want from it now.